# loop mix my child-category and parent-category

Tags: loop, categories, children

i explain the situatio I'm having:

I have a blog, which on the homepage, have display the most recent post.

For each post category, I have set up one specific color and icon by css.

ex: for category pet:

```
article.category-pets .meta-category a {
color: white;
float: left;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 25px;
background: url(http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/pets-30_30.png) no-repeat left;
background-size: 15px 15px;
background-color: #a2591e;
background-position-x: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
```

which works perfectly.

The Loop i'm using to display the category name is:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

What i would like to achieve is:

Display only the child-category of the post ( If the post is linked to a child category and his parent category) - and if the post is setup to only one parent category - display this parent category.

This loop works not really good, because, If i have my post linked for example:

Parent Category A
Child Category A1

and

Parent Category B
Child category B1

It is going to mess it up, in my case it display the child-category name ( eg. B1) - but with the icon and background-color of the Parent-Category A.

IT should display only the name of Child-Category A - with background-color and icon of A / not of B.

I can not use a loop to display only child-category or only parent-category because some post ( there is thousands) are only setup to a parent category.

I would really love any helps in that, would be lovely !

Thank you for all your time :)

--EDIT -- I add the article produced:

This is example when it works fine, because the post is only setup to one parent-category and its child

```
    <article class="post-3546 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-pet-of-the-week category-pets vce-post vce-lay-c">

<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://mywebsite.com/pets/pet-of-the-week/pets-sale-5th-feb/" title="Pets For Sale On (5th Feb)">Pets For Sale On (5th Feb)</a></h2>

    <div class="meta-image">        
                    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/pets/pet-of-the-week/pets-sale--5th-feb/" title="Pets For Sale On (5th Feb)">

            <img width="292" height="195" src="http:/mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/siberian-husky.jpg" class="attachment-vce-lay-b wp-post-image" alt="Siberian Husky For Sale" />                           </a>

                            <span class="meta-category">    
     <a href="http://mywebsite.com/category/pets/pet-of-the-week/">Pet Of The Week</a>
</span> 
            </div>


<header class="entry-header">

    <div class="entry-meta"><div class="meta-item views">26 Views</div><div class="meta-item date"><span class="updated">2 weeks ago</span></div></div>
</header>

        <div class="entry-content">
        <p>As another month rolls in, with it comes a fresh supply of adorable pets for your viewing pleasure...</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here it's when its not working correctly, because the post is attach to 3 parents cvategory and some of their child - so it mixed it up display the name of a child-category, but the background-colro and icon of another parent-category . . .

```
<article class="post-3107 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-bedroom-2 category-business-and-finance category-childrens category-home-garden category-london category-money-saving category-others category-selling-and-advertising tag-cleaning tag-clutter tag-declutter tag-home tag-house tag-london tag-sell tag-space tag-summer tag-to-do-list vce-post vce-lay-c">

     <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://mywebsite.com/others/london/home/" title="A Guide to Clearing Out the Clutter : You Can De-junk Your House in a Weekend">A Guide to Clearing Out the Clutter : You...</a></h2>

        <div class="meta-image">        
                        <a href="http://mywebsite.com/others/london/home/" title="A Guide to Clearing Out the Clutter : You Can De-junk Your House in a Weekend">

                <img width="225" height="195" src="http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AM-quotes-laundryTsunami-final-Edited.jpg" class="attachment-vce-lay-b wp-post-image" alt="AM-quotes-laundryTsunami-final - Edited" />                           </a>

                                <span class="meta-category">    
         <a href="http://mywebsite.com/category/home-garden/bedroom-2/">Bedroom</a>
    </span> 
                </div>


    <header class="entry-header">

        <div class="entry-meta"><div class="meta-item views">7 Views</div><div class="meta-item date"><span class="updated">7 months ago</span></div></div>
    </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
            <p>OUT with the Old&#8230;  A Guide to Clearing Out the Clutter : You Can De-junk Your House in a...</p>
        </div>
    </article>
```

----- EDIT - 2 relevant code ---

```
<article <?php post_class('vce-post vce-lay-c'); ?>>



    <?php if($fimage = vce_featured_image('vce-lay-b')): ?>


        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>"><?php echo vce_get_title('lay-c'); ?></a></h2>

        <div class="meta-image">        
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>">

                <?php echo $fimage; ?>
                <?php if($icon = vce_post_format_icon('lay_c')) :?>
                    <span class="vce-format-icon">
                    <i class="fa <?php echo $icon; ?>"></i>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>

            <?php if( vce_get_option('lay_c_cat')) : ?>
            <?php if (function_exists('z_taxonomy_image_url')) echo z_taxonomy_image_url(); ?>
        <span class="meta-category">    
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>

    </span> 
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <header class="entry-header">

        <div class="entry-meta"><?php echo vce_get_meta_data('lay-c'); ?></div>
    </header>

    <?php if( vce_get_option('lay_c_excerpt')) : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php echo vce_get_excerpt('lay-c'); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</article>
```

Comment: Please post the `<article>` tag that your template produces.

Comment: Please also post the relevant code from you template that produces the `<article>`.

Comment: Thank you for your time guys, the loop is insert in the  <span class="meta-category">    Hope it helps better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you posted, the article is styled according to the css rule(s) for `category-selling-and-advertising` which is defined last (among the `category-*` classes) in the article's `class` attribute.

You need to intercept the functionality of `post_class()` to change the order these classes appear. The `post_class` filter will do the job for you:

```
add_filter(
  'post_class',
  function($classes) // $classes is an array
    {
    $cats=get_the_category();
    $master_cat=$cats[0]->slug;
    if($k=array_search("category-$master_cat",$classes))
      {
      unset($classes[$k]);
      $classes[]="category-$master_cat";
      }
    return $classes;
    }
  );
```

The above is a rather naive solution, but I think it's a good place to start.

Comment: HI, Hm yes you re totally right, I understand more or less - But my functions / php / query skills are really low. I Suppose I need to add this in the functions.php - But How can I set up one ? IF you have tie to give me an example .. . . it would be wonderfull . . . .

Comment: Most probably there's a `functions.php` in your theme's directory, but I'd suggest you make a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). OTOH, you could put this code in a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) which is the way I prefer to do things myself.

Comment: Hi,Thank you,

Jsut another question, is there any this I have to change in this code ? ( I mean - where I add my category name/ID,etc ?)

WHen i add this code in my function.sphp from my child theme, I get a code mistake in classes[]="category-$master_cat";
}

THank you for your time . ..

Comment: Oops! You're right, it's `$classes` instead of `classes`. Edited my answer. My bad, sorry! :)

Comment: Hi again, thank you . . but it doenst work :( I've zero post get display with this code . . . .:( SHould I change 'post-class' by a specific class fro my theme ? Or let this code raw as it is ?

Comment: I've made some modifications. Try it like that.

Comment: Hi Back :) Thank you for your time . . but it doesn't change anything. I have still the same problem: It display the name of one of the child-category - but put the css style of another Parent-category :( Do you have any solutions in mind ? :( Thank you ;)

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know, it worked on a test installation of mine. Maybe you should play around with it for a while, see what it affects and figure out the concept behind it. After all, as I said, it's a naive, generic solution -- something to give you clues and get you started. YOU must do the real work.

Comment: Hi . . hm just wondering adfer I have dd thsi into my function. ..  what should I put in my loop ?

Comment: I have try the following withotu sucess: <a href="#" class="<?php  $master_cat = get_the_category();
echo $master_cat[0]->slug; if($k=array_search("category-$master_cat",$classes))
      {
      unset($classes[$k]);
      $classes[]="category-$master_cat";
      }
    return $classes;
     
  ?>"><?php single_cat_title('') ?></a>

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question for this. This answer's comments have stretched long enough, and this is not a forum. :)